# Kotlin Gradle using dependencies

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to include `org.apache.commons.net.*` libraries in Kotlin using Gradle and command line.

In the dependencies in my `build.gradle.kts` file I wrote:

`compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'` as it's said in the [apache documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/dependency-info.html) but it gives me a weird errors as:

```
> Configure project :
e: D:\core\Confidential\Learn\Kotlin\build.gradle.kts:30:13: Too many characters
 in a character literal ''commons-net:commons-net:3.6''

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\core\Confidential\Learn\Kotlin\build.gradle.kts' line: 30

* What went wrong:
Script compilation error:

  Line 30:     compile('commons-net:commons-net:3.6')
                       ^ Too many characters in a character literal ''commons-ne
t:commons-net:3.6''

1 error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

(I also tried with `compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'` and `compile group: 'commons-net', name: 'commons-net', version: '3.6'`).

I'm totally new with Kotlin and I'm trying to familiarize myself with it before starting Android development on IDEA.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just like in Java, `'` is for character literals, and `"` is for String literals.

You want `"commons-net:commons-net:3.6"`.

And `compile()` is deprecated. Use `implementation()`.